# Is it possible to move the buff icons in the inventory screen?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I recently moved to 1.18, and in the inventory screen now I have the buff icons on the right rather than the left as before.

This new layout is interfering with the GUI of some mods I use.

Is there an option I can toggle somewhere to revert to the old layout?